# How to pass ref of component up three levels for scroll event?

Tags: reactjs

I am using the `<InfiniteScroll/>` component in my code like this:

```
<div style="height:700px;overflow:auto;" ref={(ref) => this.scrollParentRef = ref}>
    <div>
        <InfiniteScroll
            pageStart={0}
            loadMore={loadFunc}
            hasMore={true || false}
            loader={<div className="loader" key={0}>Loading ...</div>}
            useWindow={false}
            getScrollParent={() => this.scrollParentRef}
        >
            {items}
        </InfiniteScroll>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to pass the from `ref = {(ref) => this.scrollParentRef = ref; }` to the component's grandparent, however my code does not work as expected. Here is my full component source code:

```
 class AppEmpty extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }

      componentDidMount(){
        this.props.setReferences(this.scrollParentRef);
      }

      render() {
        const { children } = this.props;
        const isActive = this.props.isActive;

        return (
          <div className="App">

            <NavBar/>

            <MenuRight/>

            <div id="content"
              className={isActive ? "content_enable": ""}
              style={this.props.menuRight.styleContent}
              ref={ (ref) => this.scrollParentRef = ref }
            >
              <FlashMessages/>
              {children}
            </div>

          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    AppEmpty.protoTypes = {
      children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
    };

    function mapsStateToProps(state){
      return {
        menuRight: state.menuRight,
        isActive: state.isActive,
      };


    }

    export default connect (mapsStateToProps, {setReferences})(AppEmpty);
```

The documentation says:

> getScrollParent Function Override method to return a different scroll listener if it's not the immediate parent of InfiniteScroll.

Can someone suggest a way to pass that reference in an easy way to the `<InfiniteScroll/>`?

Answer (score 1):

After trying everything, I realized that I can pass as a refs using document.getElementById ('comp_id_a_referenciar') :(

Content-> compomente_base -> form_busqueda, Tables -> InfiniteScroll(Refs_Content).

```
<div>
<InfiniteScroll
    pageStart={0}
    loadMore={loadFunc}
    hasMore={true || false}
    loader={<div className="loader" key={0}>Loading ...</div>}
    useWindow={false}
    getScrollParent={ () => document.getElementById('content') }
>
    {items}
</InfiniteScroll>
```

working! nice!

Answer (score 0):

Create a ref container using `useRef()` hook

```js
import { useRef } from "react";

const scrollContainerRef = useRef(null);
```

then put the `ref={scrollContainerRef}` on the `<div>` and `useWindow={false}` to `<InfiniteScroll>`

```
<div className="px-6 py-4 overflow-auto" ref={scrollContainerRef}>
   <InfiniteScroll
     useWindow={false}
     getScrollParent={() => scrollContainerRef.current}
   >
    // code here...
   </InfiniteScroll>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).